# Error no envio de MDFe

Tags: java, eclipse

A empresa onde trabalho tem um projeto Java feito no Eclipse pra envio de NFSe e MDFe. Anda ocorrendo um erro quando tento enviar um MDFe. O log do erro está no link do pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/jNimHEmS

Comment: "*unable to find valid certification path to requested target*" - Ou seja, você tem que configurar a cadeia de certificados. Se prepare, porque esse é um processo chato, doloroso, tortuoso e inglório de se fazer. Ainda mais usando a droga do Axis.

Comment: É, me contrataram pra tomar conta desse Frankstein mal escrito, gerado a partir de uma série de decisões ruins tomadas ao longo dos anos. Teria alguma ideia de qual certificado específico eu devo adicionar, e como adicionar?

Comment: A última vez que tive o desprazer de mexer com cadeia de certificado foi há 9 anos atrás, então não lembro mais. Mas você pode procurar nos endpoints do WSDL e talvez nos namescapes do XML quais são as URLs para as quais você precisa ter a cadeia de certificados. Na época que trabalhei com isso, era o certificado do ICP-Brasil que precisava ser instalado para NFe, então talvez começar a procurar por isso te ajude.

Comment: Ok, valeu. Vou tentar achar os certificados.